# How to detect a click on a component that is not visible

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to detect a click on a picturebox that is not visible

I have tried this :

```
    private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("teste");
    }
```

But even if the picture box has no image and that background color is transparent, it hides the elements behind it.

I explain myself a little better;

I do a tic-tac-toe and I have the image of the cross that is not visible when the game is started; as soon as I press on a delimited area (where I want to place the cross), I want it to become visible

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Use the MouseDown event of the container and examine the mouse coordinates with the location of the invisible control.

Comment: Yes !
That's it, thank you very much. It really helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the PictureBox with an ImageList containing 2 images: the first is the background of your game field and the second is the cross.
In your Click Event I would toggle the pictures on click then.

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to stay on my technique. Any other solution for my problem?